# how to select from drop down list in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have drop down list showing existing tag/chip that all user created in the past but I'm not sure why when I select one from drop down list, the item is not showing in my input field (just like Chart tag right now). I'm able create chip/tags by inputting text and pressing enter but I also want the feature where I user can just select a tags that have been created by someone from drop down list.

Chart tag is example that I created by entering it (not selected from the list)

Will be really appreciated if anyone can give me suggestion or help me.

TS

```
  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    const tag = {tag: event.option.viewValue, type: TagType.user};
    this.normalTags.push(tag);
    if(this.input){
      this.input.nativeElement.value = "";
    }
    this.tagCtrl2.setValue(null);
    //remove the selected one from the option list
    var index = this.allTagNames.indexOf(tag.tag);
    this.allTagNames.splice(index, 1);
    this.mapper();
  }

  mapper(){
    this.filteredTags = this.tagCtrl2.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((tag: string | null) => tag ? this._filter(tag) : this.allTagNames.slice()))
  }
```

HTML

```
    <mat-form-field class="demo-chip-list" appearance="fill">
        <mat-chip-list #chipList>
            <mat-chip  *ngFor="let chip of chips" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeTags(chip)">
                {{chip.tag}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="chip.pending !== true && removable" matTooltip="Remove a tag">cancel</mat-icon>
                <mat-spinner *ngIf="chip.pending === true" [diameter]="16" mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
            </mat-chip>

            <input matInput  #input [(ngModel)]="tagIn" placeholder="Select or Create a tag" [formControl]="tagCtrl2" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                (focusout)="hideTagInput()" (keyup.enter)="addTag()"(keyup.escape)="hideTagInput()"
                (keydown.backspace)="$event.stopPropagation();" (keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation();" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" />
        </mat-chip-list>

        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">
                {{tag}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are adding the tags to the HTML? and function mapper?

Comment: @BrenoAntunes Hi.. I just add more code above and also I upload the whole code in stackblitz over here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ynuoq9 . Please let me know.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like that you are using both Reactive Forms and Template Drive Forms in the same input. If it is not a requirement, I would consider to remove and leave this way (Reactive forms):

```
<input matInput placeholder="Select or Create a tag" [formControl]="tagCtrl2" 
[matAutocomplete]="auto" (focusout)="hideTagInput()" (keyup.enter)="addTag()"
(keyup.escape)="hideTagInput()" (keydown.backspace)="$event.stopPropagation();" 
(keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation();" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" />
```

(Will need to refactor you component.ts if you change)

But answering your question:

On the selected function you are not adding the tag to the chips array, and the chips array is the one that you are using to show the tags, so you will need to change to:

```
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) : void {
    const tag = {tag: event.option.viewValue, type: TagType.user};
    this.normalTags.push(tag);
    this.chips.push(tag); <---- new line
    if(this.input){
      this.input.nativeElement.value = "";
    }
    this.tagCtrl2.setValue(null);
    var index = this.allTagNames.indexOf(tag.tag);
    this.allTagNames.splice(index, 1);
    this.mapper();
  }
```

Comment: thanks you for providing me this but can you please help me fix this.. I've been stuck for a couple of day now since I took over this task from my co-worker and complete lost.

Comment: Help you fix what exactly?
I updated my answer with the line you need to add, let me know if it fix the problem

Comment: can you help me to refector component.ts file. I just add those code and now it showing when I select but  it's not  actually storing. when I referesh the browser the chip is gone. and also I can't create a new chip anymore by entering it. I would be really appreciated if you can help me.. please

Comment: It's not persisting the data because it is just storing in an array. I don't have access to all your project, but you have a service to add the tags you need to call this service passing the new tag. 
I don't know which component is receiving events from "tagAdded.emit", but probably it is calling the service from there. If it is not calling the service, then you will need to call from the component.